# Powershell problematic without working code changes

Tags: comments, echo, hashtable, write-host

I have several points of working code that now no longer works.  Here is a block of code:

```
if ($day -eq 01) {
    echo "The Day of Days" }
else {
    echo "Not Today" }
```

I get the following result:

```
At D:\PS_Scripts\Archive-Log.ps1:88 char:15
+         echo "The Day of Days" }
+               ~~~
Unexpected token 'The' in expression or statement.
```

I tried with Write-host and get the same thing:

```
At D:\PS_Scripts\Archive-Log.ps1:88 char:21
+         Write-Host "The Day of Days" }
+                     ~~~
Unexpected token 'The' in expression or statement.
```

I've also run into problems with Comment lines and get the following:

```
At D:\PS_Scripts\Archive-Log.ps1:87 char:29
+ #                {($_ -ieq "LOG") } {
+                             ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'LOG") } {
#                    Write-LogRecord -M $Return.message }
#                {($_ -ieq "NOLOG")} {
#                    Write-Host $Return.message }
#                default {
#                    Write-Host '$msgE1' 
#                    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $global:USER_SOURCE `
#                        -EventID 4001 -EntryType Information -Message "$msgE1"
#                    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $global:USER_SOURCE `
#                        -EventID 2001 -EntryType Error -Message $Return.message } }
```

I also have problems with returning a Hash Table to the calling program which worked and no longer works as shown here:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".
At D:\PS_Scripts\Archive-Log.ps1:82 char:9
+         $ReturnCD = Create-Directory -D $ArchiveDir
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```